# How does C++ compiler represent int numbers in binary code?

Tags: c++, binary

I've written a program, which shows binary representation of a particular integer value, using bitwise operators in C++. For even numbers it works as I expect, but for odd it adds 1 to the left of the binary representation.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 128;

    for (int i = sizeof(a) * 8; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (a & (1UL << i)) { // if i-th digit is 1
            cout << 1;        // Output 1
        }
        else {
            cout << 0;        // Otherwise output 0
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

- For a = 128: 000000000000000000000000010000000,
- For a = 127: **1**00000000000000000000000001111111

Comment: Your first shift will be by 32 (assuming 32bit int). That's one too far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You might prefer CHAR_BIT macro instead of raw 8 (`#include <climits>`).
2. Consider your start value! Assuming `unsigned int` having 32 bit, your start value is `int i = 4*8`, so `1U << i` shifts the value out of range. This is undefined behaviour and could result in anything, obviously, your specific compiler *or* hardware shifts `%32`, thus you get an initial `value & 1`, resulting in the unexpected leading 1... Did you notice that you actually printed out 33 digits instead of only 32?

Comment: Because of *least* significant bit of even  numbers being 0; be aware that due to the overflow, you check this one instead of the most significant one in the very first loop run.

Comment: Sorry, now I see. I just forgot, that numbering bits starts from 0. So, to check the left-most bit, I have to set i equal to sizeof(a) * CHAR_BIT - 1, in order it to shift 1UL 31 position to the left. Now it works just fine! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
for (int i = sizeof(a) * 8; i >= 0; --i) {
```

it should be:

```
for (int i = sizeof(a) * 8; i-- ; ) {
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cb2b745063883fa

Comment: On the one hand I like the neatness of it, while on the other hand I don't like that the loop body works with a different value than the condition check... Still, neat and insightful.

Comment: Elegant solution, I liked it, when I understood it, but it's not so clear

Comment: @StoryTeller Now you mention it, I see the philosophical problem with mixing the concerns of counting and bit-indexing. It never occurred to me to do it any other way. I learned C from the K&R book 30+ years ago, before that it was assembler. I guess old habits die hard. :)